# Error #2044 when trying to save image from Flash using php

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I get this error in the debugger version of flash Player 
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error

i searched the net for an explanation without success

the code below works in WampServer http://localhost/ but not when i put it online on the server:

as3 :

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
```

var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(img_mc.width,img_mc.height);
jpgSource.draw(img_mc);
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);

//set the request's header,method and data
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type","application/octet-stream");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
//sends jpg bytes to saveJPG.php script
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("saveJPG.php");
myRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
myRequest.data = jpgStream;
loader.load(myRequest);
//fire complete event;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,saved);
function saved(e:Event)
{
    //trace the image file name
    trace(loader.data);
}

saveJPG.php:

```
if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) {
```

```
//the image file name   
$fileName = 'img.jpg';

// get the binary stream
$im = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

//write it
$fp = fopen($fileName, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $im);
fclose($fp);

//echo the fileName;
echo $fileName;
```

}  else echo 'result=An error occured.';

update:

i tried  `$im = file_get_contents("php://input");`

instead of `$im = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];`

and i got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("saveJPG.php");
```

Try to set complete url for request.

Answer (score 1):

```
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error
```

Do what it wants add the unhandled ioError eventlistener

```
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler );
function ioErrorHandler( e:Event ):void{
  trace('ioErrorHandler ' + e.toString() )
}
```

And you should have this one also

```
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler );
function securityErrorHandler ( e:Event ):void{
  trace('securityErrorHandler ' + e.toString() )
}
```

Comment: @isa did you add the events I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the server is preventing me from exchanging bytes or using `$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];` or something like that.

so i come up with different approach, instead of sending the image as bytes to php file 
i'll send it as hexadecimal string:

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
```

var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(img_mc.width,img_mc.height);
jpgSource.draw(img_mc);
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(80);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);

//get the whole jpgStream as a string of hex
var hexStream:String="";
for (var i:int=0;i < jpgStream.length ; i++)
{
    hexStream += decToHex(jpgStream[i]);
}

function decToHex(dec:int):String
{
    var hex:String = dec.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    if (dec<16)
    {
        hex = "0"+hex;
    }
    return hex;
}

//transfer hexStream to the server

var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.hexStream = hexStream;

var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("saveimg.php");
myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
myRequest.data = variables;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myRequest);
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY
loader.load(myRequest);

on the server side just one line of php code

```
file_put_contents('img.jpg', pack('H*', $_POST['hexStream']));
```

obviously this is slower than using `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`
but hey

Comment: This is not the answer to your question. This is a fix for another bug you have where you are trying to send JPG data via post which you can not do due to the fact that JPG data contains backslashes in it. Which is why most people will convert to base64 instead of 16 because then there is less data to post also.

Comment: @The_asMan interesting... i will check that later thank you for your comment.